# startxwin.exe is failing in cygwin 1.13.2.0 on Windows 7 with keyboard initialization failure

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, keymap

My operating system is Windows 7. I installed cygwin. I wanted to start the XWin Server with the `startxwin` command and it terminates with the error:

```
 Couldn't open compiled keymap file /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
(EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
(EE) Couldn't open compiled keymap file /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
XKB: Failed to compile keymap
Keyboard initialization failed. This could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.
Fatal server error: Failed to activate core devices.
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
startxwin: giving up
startxwin: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
startxwin: server error
```

I already tried `/usr/bin/rebaseall -v` and it didn't solve the problem and gives the same error.

Could someone please help me overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that xkeyboard-config is correctly installed using `cygcheck -c xkeyboard-config`
- Check that `/usr/bin/xkbcomp` can be run from a bash shell. If that fails, see if `cygcheck /usr/bin/xkbcomp` reports any missing DLLs.
- Something is interfering with the ability of the X server to invoke `xkbcomp` to compile the keymap.

Possible causes:

- You have run Cygwin's setup program to do an update while some cygwin processes were running, and then clicked on the continue option in the "In-use files detected" dialog, and then tried to carry on using Cygwin without rebooting as advised by setup. Reboot.
- This is one of the symptoms of an application interfering with Cygwin's fork() emulation. See the [main Cygwin FAQ question](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) for a list of software which has been known to interfere with the correct operation of Cygwin.
- This also caused by DLLs with conflicting base addresses preventing Cygwin's fork() emulation from functioning correctly. Install the rebase package, read the README file `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/rebase-n.n.n.README`, and follow the instructions there to run `rebaseall`. In short: stop all Cygwin processes (including services) and run `rebaseall` from an `ash` shell (not `bash`, which would open some DLLs, making them unwriteable) in a `cmd.exe` window.

Source: http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-failed-to-compile-keymap

Comment: Actually there is no such file by the name of server-0.xkm in /var/lib/xkb/

Is it usual for these folders to have no keymaps by default? Coz I am sure I didn't remove it. I installed cygwin very recently.

Comment: I just installed it, and all there is in there is `/var/lib/xkb/README.compiled`.  Just that one file.

Comment: I am able to run the X server, so it is not required to have `server-0.xkm`

Comment: I tried for many hours and tried all your suggestions for no avail. But thanks for all your suggestions coz while going through them I learnt new things. Now I am completely uninstalling cygwin and would be reinstalling shortly.